# Insert Objects in a Constant Length List - Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am looking for a good optimal strategy to write a code for the following problem.

I have a List of Objects.

1. The Objects have a String "valuation" field among other fields.  The valuation field may or may not be unique.
2. The List is of CONSTANT length which is calculated within the program. The length would usually be between 100 and 500.
3. The Objects are all sorted within the list based on String field - valuation
4. As new objects are found or created:  The String field valuation is compared with the existing members of the list.
5. If the comparison fails e.g. with the bottom member of the list, then the Object is NOT added to the list.
6. If the comparison succeeds and the new Object is added to the list - within the sort criteria;the new object is added in the right position and the bottom member is ousted from the list to keep the length of the list constant.

One strategy which I am thinking:

1. Keep adding members to the list - till it reaches maxLength
2. Sort - (e.g Collections.sort with a comparator) the list
3. When a new member is created - compare it with the bottom member of the list.
4. If success - replace the bottom member else continue
5. Re-Sort the List - if success

and continue.

The program loops through million or more iterations, thus optimized comparison and running has become an issue.

Any guidance on a good strategy to address this within the Java domain.  What lists will be the most effective e.g. LinkedList or ArrayLists or Sets etc.  Which sort/insert (standard package) will be the most effective?

Comment: Is valuation unique? I'd say use a TreeMap or TreeSet as a base for your implementation. Searching is fast that way and inserting okay as well.

Comment: @Jan.. No the valuation may or may not be  unique.  i.e. if equals the bottom member then - don't add.   I also updated the question.

Comment: Still TreeSet might be best choice - but you need fast Comparator.

Comment: Thanks @ Jan.  Read some good examples of Treeset [link](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/treeset/java-util-treeset-example/) here.  This link also has a good example of compare and comparator.   What do you mean by a "Fast Comparator" ?

Comment: Ah scratch that. You'll be comparing Strings anyways. So nothing big to do wrong there in terms of performance.

Comment: @userDSSR Oh, you just accepted his solution, you can take a look at my solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this example based on TreeSet and comparing over a String for Results. As you can see, after enough iterations, only elements with very large keys are left in List. On my quite old laptop, I had 10.000 items in less than 50ms - so roundabout 5s per million list operations.

```
public class Valuation {

    public static class Element implements Comparable<Element> {
        String valuation;
        String data;
        Element(String v, String d) {
            valuation = v;
            data = d;
        }
        @Override
        public int compareTo(Element e) {           
            return valuation.compareTo(e.valuation);
        }       
    }

    private TreeSet<Element> ts = new TreeSet<Element>();

    private final static int LISTLENGTH = 500;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("00000");
        Random r = new Random();
        Valuation v = new Valuation();
        for(long l = 1; l < 150; ++l) {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for(int j = 0; j < 10000; ++j) {
                v.pushNew(new Element(nf.format(r.nextInt(50000))
                                , UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
            }
            System.out.println("10.000 finished in " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-start) + "ms. Set contains: " + v.ts.size());
        }
        for(Element e : v.ts) {
            System.out.println("-> " + e.valuation);
        }
    }

    private void pushNew(Element hexString) {
        if(ts.size() < LISTLENGTH) {
            ts.add(hexString);
        } else {
            if(ts.first().compareTo(hexString) < 0) {
                ts.add(hexString);
                if(ts.size() > LISTLENGTH) {
                    ts.remove(ts.first());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you supposed to be removing the _last_ (biggest) element from the set, rather than the first?

Comment: Also, no need to check `if (ts.size() > LISTLENGTH)` as you already know it is.

Answer (score 0):

> Any guidance on a good strategy to address this within the Java domain.

My advice would be - there is no need to do any sorting. You can ensure your data is sorted by doing binary insertion as you add more objects into your collection.

This way, as you add more items, the collection itself is already is a sorted state.

After the 500th item, if you want to add another one, we just perform another binary insertion. The insertion performance always remains at O(log(n)) and there is no need to perform any sorting.

**Comparing with your algorithm**

Your algorithm works fine from 1 - 4. But step 5 will likely be the bottle neck of your algorithm:

> 5.Re-Sort the List - if success

This is because even though your list will only have a maximum of 500 items, but there can be infinite number of insertions to be performed on this list after the 500th item is being added.

Imagine having another 1 million more insertions and (in worse case scenario), all 1 million items "succeeded" and can be inserted into the list, that implies your algorithm will need to perform 1 million more sorts!
That will be `1 million * n(log(n))` for sorting.

Compare with binary insertion, in the worse case it will be `1 million * log(n)` for insertion (no sorting).

> What lists will be the most effective e.g. LinkedList or ArrayLists or Sets etc.

If you use ArrayList, insertion won't be as efficient as compared to a linked list since ArrayList is backed by an array. However accessing of elements is only O(1) for arrayList as compare to linked list which is O(n). So there isn't a data structure which is efficient for all scenarios. You will have to plan your algorithm first and see which one fits best for your strategy.

> Which sort/insert (standard package) will be the most effective?

As far as I know, there is `Arrays.sort()` and `Collections.sort()` available which will give you a good performance of O(n log(n)) as they are using a dual pivot sort which will be more effective than a simple insertion/bubble/selection sort created by yourself.

Comment: One more option is to use a plain old array, since the size is constant.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou That can be one of the options.